# Ordenar por um valor especifico

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o plugin [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) e em uma coluna eu possuo a seguinte estrutura

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o037az6v/)**

E por padrão o plugin cria a forma de ordenação padrão da qual não sei que regra obedece, gostaria que quando clicar nessa coluna para ordenar ele fizesse a ordenação pelo valor da classe `.saldo`

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Quando você clica em Informações e a seta esta para cima a ordenação que ele faz e a crescente usando o seu `.saldo` como base, coloquei os valores 1,5.2, na primeira ordenação o 5 que estava no meio vai para ultimo por ser maior que 2

Comment: Mas esses valores precisam ficar juntos na mesma coluna ? http://jsfiddle.net/o037az6v/2/

Comment: Não, é que na verdade a estrutura real é um pouco mais complexa então usei essa de exemplo reduzida... Cada coluna seria cada loja e as linhas seria as vendas por produto, então preciso ter toda essa informação nessa td @DiegoSouza

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema usando o atributo `data-order` que é possível customizar o valor usado na hora do order

Visualizado no **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o037az6v/3/)**

**[Documentação](https://www.datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5)**